# Top loader washing machine fill valve drips continuously

Tags: electrical, water, drain, washing-machine, leaking

I have a top loader washing machine. When it's done washing it keeps dripping from the top fill valve, where the water fills up the drum.[image]

Comment: The valve may be failing or it may be crudded up with hard water deposits, for example. Does it eventually stop dripping or is it perpetual?

Comment: sounds like the solenoid valve is leaking... not a terrible DIY job if your comfortable with the disassembly/ re-assembly. look for an online video for your machine type.

Comment: hi Isherwood it never stops dripping.thanks

Comment: H Mark I tried to run some demineralizer solution thru it. maybe clean it out but that didn't work

Comment: Well, unless you tell us more about your hardware, cleaning/replacement are about all the advice we can give. If you want specific answers, ask specific questions.

Comment: Next time I'm over there willl get some other info on the machine thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Solenoid Valve is leaking.  It is an easy repair if you are comfortable with disassembly and re-assembly of the machine.
[image: example of valve]

It should be about a $20-50 part depending on your machine.  It may be possible to replace the soft goods in the valve and repair it, but its probably not worth it as all the work is in taking the machine apart and putting it back together.

Comment: Although I agree an easy job it may be something like a small chunk of crud or even a fine piece of plastic on the seat swap out should be 100% fix but disassemble and clean the solenoid would only take time, it might be a good plan to get the new assembly then try the tear down if you damage the assembly toss and install the new if repaired return the unused part.

Comment: Hey Mark do you have the link to the part I need I added a picture what's the model number excetera thanks.

Comment: here is the non- OEM part: https://www.amazon.com/Clothes-Whirlpool-Kenmore-Frigidaire-Electrolux/dp/B074124N36/ref=asc_df_B074124N36/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198070787462&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11235925285679360497&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9030241&hvtargid=pla-362155928043&psc=1

Comment: here is the OEM replacement: https://www.genuinereplacementparts.com/estate-etw4400wq1-water-inlet-valve-genuine-oem